# Compute the Integral via Residue Theorem and Laurent Expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Let $f(z)=\dfrac{z^{15}}{(z^2+1)^2(z^4+2)^3}$ . My goal is to compute $\displaystyle I=\int_{|z|=4}f(z) \,dz$.

Since all the singular points (except $∞$) lie in the circle $|z|<4$, we obtain $I=-2\pi i\operatorname{Res}(f,∞)$. Thus, we just need to find the Laurent coefficient $a_{-1}$ at $∞$.

$f\left(\dfrac 1 w\right) = \dfrac w {(1+w^2)^2(1+2w^4)^3}$. Any convenient ways to find $a_{-1}$?

Comment: I don't think you need a residue at infinity, just those inside the circle.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Finding the residue at infintity is much easier to do than finding the residues at the six singular point inside the circle $C$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find $Res_{w = 0} \left[\frac 1{w^2}f\left(\frac 1w \right)\right] = Res_{w = 0} \left[\dfrac 1{w(1+w^2)^2(1+2w^4)^3}\right]$ . Now we have:

$$a_{-1} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_0} \frac {dw}{w(1+w^2)^2(1+2w^4)^3} = \frac{1}{(1+0^2)^2(1+2\cdot 0^4)^4} = 1$$

by Cauchy Integral Formula, as $\frac{1}{(1+w^2)^2(1+2w^4)^3}$ is analytic at $C_0$, which can be taken as any curve inside a disk $|z| \le \frac 14$, for example.

---

A direct way of finding the residue is to use partial fraction decomposition. We have:

$$\dfrac 1{w(1+w^2)^2(1+2w^4)^3} = \frac Aw + \frac{F(w)}{(1+w^2)^2(1+2w^4)^3}$$ Now it's not har to see that $A = a_{-1}$, so multiply both sides by $w$ and evaluate it at $w=0$

Comment: Why you compute $Res(\frac{1}{w^2}f(\frac{1}{w}),0)$ instead of $Res(f({\frac{1}{w}}),0)$?

Comment: @KangpingYan Note that when you introduce the change of variable $z = \frac 1w$ in the integral we have that $dz = -\frac{1}{w^2} dw$. So in fact $-Res_{z = \infty} f(z) = Res_{w = 0} \frac {1}{w^2} f\left( \frac 1w \right)$